# Integration of a function involving algebraic and trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, approximate-integration

Evaluate $$f(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan{x})}dx$$

My attempt: I could not apply any standard method known to me to solve this integration. The only way I thought of is expressing $\tan(x)$ as an infinite series and expanding into a polynomial. But this will introduce approximation errors. 
$$f(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(x + \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+...)}dx$$
$$or, f(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2}{(1+x^2)^{-1}(x + \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+...)^{-1}}dx$$
Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541463/computing-int-limits-0-pi-2-1-over-18-sin2-tan-x-dx/2541499#2541499

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx

Comment: It is a duplicate of the above link